# How to import anchor-lang with the init-if-needed cargo feature enabled

Tags: anchor, solana-program, pda

I was writing rust code where I used init_if_needed. Got the following error:

```
init_if_needed requires that anchor-lang be imported with the init-if-needed 
cargo feature enabled. Carefully read the init_if_needed docs before using 
this feature to make sure you know how to protect yourself against re-initialization attacks.
```

how do I  import anchor-lang with the init-if-needed cargo feature enabled

Answer (score 5):

add this in the `cargo.toml`file

```
anchor-lang = {version = "0.25.0", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
```